# How to add a value in a matrix and make it decrease in radial way?

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix

I got a `matrix` with odd lines and columns and all positions with 0 (zero) values, I want to add an X value (16 for example) at the center position of the `matrix` and make the other positions around to decrease an Y value (3 for example) but in a `radial` way, until those positions reach zero.

Like this image I created (I added colors just for better understanding):

[image]

I'm starting to work with matrices, I searched the web for something similar that could help but nothing very understandable. How that could be done? There is some `for-loop` trick to do this? Anyone had tried before? If someone could help I'll be grateful.

Comment: What trouble are you having. You can make an array with these numbers in. Or do you wish to construct matrices of arbitrary size. In which case, what are the rules of the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I didn't explain well. The matrix will have all initial values=0, I need a function to keep adding values at random positions inside the matrix, and the positions around must add lower values in radial way, until reach zero, like heatmaps.

Comment: So use the values that you show here. How hard can it be? It's not like you need to compute the values. Put them in an array and copy them into the big array.

Comment: I asked because I got no skills with matrices, this image and values was not generated by a code.

Comment: You don't need very much skill. It's just a nested for loop to copy some pre-defined values. If you can't do that I don't see how you can do anything with this program. If you need to hire a programmer this is the wrong place. You've made no effort to show any code. Your original tagging had two languages which made me feel it was an algorithmic question. Now it seems that you just want somebody to write the code for you. I think you've given up too soon. Pretend the Internet didn't exist. Spend some time trying to think about, understand and then solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[EDIT]**

So based on you're edit i thought this solution. Since you don't specify any programming language i'll use some c-like functional programming. I'll leave you the work of transforming it to object oriented if you need it.

Input:

- Global maxtrix that starts in M[0,0] and ends in M[100'000, 100'000] (Note that, to make it easier to understand, i want check if i reach board, you should check)
- Position for first number (X,Y) (in your example 5,5)
- First number called N (in your example 16)
- Decrement for along axis D (in your example 3)

  ```
  main(){
     computeValues(M, X, Y, N, D)
  }

  computeValues(M, X, Y, N, D){
     M[X,Y] = N
     if( N-D <= 0 ) return;
     if( M[X,Y-1] == 0 ){
        computeValues(M, X, Y-1, N-D, D)
     }
     if( M[X,Y+1] == 0 ){
        computeValues(M, X, Y+1, N-D, D)
     }
     if( M[X-1,Y] == 0 ){
        computeValues(M, X-1, Y, N-D, D)
     }
     if( M[X+1,Y] == 0 ){
        computeValues(M, X+1, Y, N-D, D)
     }
  }
  ```

It should be pretty self-explanatory, anyway this function ends when reach 0 with the `N-D <= 0` control. Once a position recive the number, it check for near position not yet evaluated and assign them `N-D` number, the new position if `N-D <= 0` will continue to check for near position not evaluated and so on...

IMPORTANT NOTE: This function return the matrix as you asked in the text of your answer, which is a little bit different from the image you posted (Example `M[4,4]` in your example is 11 but it should be 10 and `M[5,0]` should be 1)

---

**OLD ANSWER**

This should not to much difficult. The only things you missed to say is how to compute value by value.

To accomplish this algorithm you need to know (and tell us, if you want) the rule or maybe the function that allow as to get the right value.

An example to make my point clearer:

```
  Y
Y X Y
  Y
```

If X=17 how do we know if Y, for example, need to be 15 or 14?

[If you edit you're answer whit those information i'll try to answer you properly]

Comment: Just awesome, I was thinking how to solve this using several `for-loop`s but you found an amazing way, very compact. Now I'll translate it to Delphi and make previously sized matrices according to N and D values and add them to the main matrix. Thanks and congratulations.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help. Good luck with your work ;)